# Generate CUDA program dlls under Linux

Tags: linux, dll, cuda, mingw, nvcc

I know that mingw creates a dll file under windows which can be used to create an exe file. We can execute this exe file in windows. I am working on a cuda project under Linux, but have to deliver the product for Windows as well. Is it possible to generate a dll file using some sort of method under windows?

Comment: MinGW is not supported by CUDA under windows. You would have to build a C++ DLL project using Visual Studio.

Comment: @sgar91: that seems like a perfect answer if you would care to post it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On windows, MinGW is not supported for CUDA development. The only compiler which is officially supported by CUDA is `cl.exe` which ships with Microsoft Visual Studio.

More details can be found in [System Requirements](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#system-requirements) section of CUDA Getting Started Guide.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx) is an MSDN tutorial which describes how to create a C++ DLL using Visual Studio.

For compiling CUDA kernels, you would have to add CUDA Build Rules in the Build Customizations section of the Visual Studio DLL project.